# Exporting a Wet map image in Blender 2.8

Tags: physics

Yeah I know how to export a wetmap in Blender 2.79 but I do not find the option in 2.8. I'm talking about the physics tab in Dynamic Paint there used to be an option to save your wetmap. In 2.8 that is just a wird symbol where you can write a title.

Answer (score 0):

With my 2.8 blender built Dynamic Paint only works in the viewport wth the render display mode and the surface canvas. Then I can export it as well and use the resultung images in an image node as a sequence to plug into my material's shader node. It does not work in eevee or in workbench or in the Look Dev mode in Cycles. It really only works in Rendered mode in Cycles with a surface Canvas. Wish I would have gotten that memo. I mean it's supposed to be a major release not a beta. Yeah I'm grumpy about this.